# adding html5 to an existing project with IE compatibility

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a web site which is defined on the IIS with compatibility for IE8
since the controls don't work well on IE9..
we do this by defining on the IIS:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8
```

I want to add HTML5 code to few of the pages.
what's the best approach for doing this without loosing the compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills)